# Make mapping repeatable with repeat.vim

Tags: repeated-commands, key-bindings

I'm trying to make a mapping that inserts an empty line below without moving the cursor and to make this repeatable with `repeat.vim`. I have modeled this from [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-repeatable-mappings-with-repeat-vim/). To get back to the original position after the `O`/`o` operation I use mark `e`. I have the code below in my `.vimrc`.

Why doesn't the code below work?

```
 Insert empty line above, repeatable
 nnoremap <silent> <Plug>EmptyLineAbove meO<ESC>`e :call repeat#set("\                      
 <Plug>EmptyLineAbove")<CR>
 nnoremap gO <Plug>EmptyLineAbove
 "Insert empty line below, repeatable
 nnoremap <silent> <Plug>EmptyLineBelow meo<ESC>`e :call repeat#set("\         
 <Plug>EmptyLineBelow")<CR>
 nnoremap go <Plug>EmptyLineBelow
```

Comment: Try maybe using `nmap` instead of `nnoremap` for `gO` and `go`

Comment: That fixed it. Could you explain why in an answer to this question?

Comment: Also I had to remove the space berfore `:call`. This moves the cursor one step to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>gO</kbd> and <kbd>go</kbd> mappings should be made with `nmap` instead of `nnoremap`. `nnoremap` disallows recursion in mappings or nesting, it's usefull for redefining commands. With `nmap` Vim scans right side of the mapping further for possible mappings. Read more with `:h :nmap` and `:h :nnoremap`.